# Small black bar at the top of screen iOS 7.1 iPhone 5

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard

There is a small black bar at the top of the screen in my iOS app. I have no idea what the issue is. It's not a launch image issue because I have the correct size for my iPhone (640 x 1136) and the other screen that are presented on top of this main view are sized correctly. What could the issue be? the height of it is less than the height of the status bar that is displayed.

Comment: Might the main window. in AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, insert this line.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
If the black space turns red, you'll know it's the main window. That could help start figuring out your issue.

Comment: Can you post an image?

Comment: You need to add way more detail to your question about your view hierarchy and what investigation you've done so far.